# How to properly perform HttpPost on onPageFinished in Android

Tags: java, php, android, http-post

In my app I have a WebView. If this WebView loads, I want to perform a `HttpPost` to fetch a variable from a script. However I keep getting Exception errors, which tell me I need to perform the `HttpPost` in `AsyncTask`. I don't know how to do this, since I'm good enough in Android developing yet.

This is the `HttpPost` I wrote:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new;   
HttpPost("myscript.php");

    try {
       // Add your data
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("website", "google.com"));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

       // Execute HTTP Post Request
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

       // writing response to log
       Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());

     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     }
```

This is my `onPageFinished` method:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView myWebView, String url)
    {

        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
        "var tetsttest = document.getElementById('menu-toggle'); tetsttest.style.display = 'none'; tetsttest.style.display = 'none'; tetsttest.style.display = 'none';" +
        "})()");

        // when a page has finished loading dismiss any progress dialog
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
     }
});
```

And this is the php file:

```
<?php

        $website = $_POST['website'];

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die("err");
    $db = mysql_select_db('database') or die("err");

    $sql = "SELECT color FROM colors WHERE website='$website'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $color = $row['color'];

    print "$color";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well all network operations in android requires to be performed in a separate thread and AsyncTask is a class that allows you to perform threading in an elegant manner(painless threading). Heres an example of asynctask:

```
public class SendRequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        //runs in ui thread 
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //perform network operations here it is the background thread
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //runs in ui thread you can update the layout here
    }
}
```

On your onpageloading finished method you can call this asynctask like this:

```
new SendRequestAsyncTask().execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I implement this in my file? Should I add it as a separate class file?

Comment: You can have it as a inner class copy all the code you have posted above HttpClient to doInbackground. Doing this will give you access to all the class variables of outer class. I generally make it innerclass for this reason

Comment: Your code works like a charm, but I am doing something wrong in my php file, since it can't properly read what the PHP sends back. (php sends 01, 02, 03, 04, 05 or 06)

Comment: I'm getting either `Http Response:﹕ [ 06-27 14:27:06.628  6574: 6574 I/NSApplication ]` or `org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@41d0bac8` as a respons.

Comment: HttpPost httppost = new;   
HttpPost("myscript.php"); your url is probably wrong in this line

Comment: No, the url is correct. I'm still getting `org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@41d0bac8`.